# Eulerian Cycle in a Random Bipartite Graph

Tags: random-graphs, bipartite-graphs, eulerian-path

I want to know (or possibly a pointer to a relevant text) the probability of having an Eulerian cycle in a random bipartite graph. I assume an Erdos-Renyi model $G(n,m,p)$, where the number of nodes on each side are respectively $n$ and $m$, and an edge exists between two nodes with probability $p$, and edges are independent. I'm interested in either exact expressions or asymptotic results.

Comment: There exists an eulerian circuit if all degrees are even,  
so you just need to estimate the probability that this happens.